# Skip Startup Scripts on Hp-UX

Tags: startup, hp-ux

Is there a way to bypass start-up scripts on HP-UX B.11.31 from rc directories. I am looking for some commands or boot mode which would do this.

Thank you,

Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct answer is it depends on which state the system should be after and what you want it to be able to do. The rc directories contain useful services that need to be started in order to have a fully working OS.
One possibility is to boot into a single user state or mode (runlevel S or 1) described here http://www.flagword.net/2010/03/runlevels-in-hp-ux-and-solaris/

I recommend using 2 runlevels, first one to boot into by default (ex.  runlevel 3) which will start the mandatory things and scripts from "/sbin/rc3.d" (ex. syslog, sshd etc.) and second one to switch to (ex. runlevel 5) which will start the applications from "/sbin/rc5.d" which are optional for the OS but required in a final state of the machine.

So the machine should boot by default in runlevel 3 (specified as default in /etc/inittab), then you login to the machine and use the command `telinit 5` to switch the system to runlevel 5 starting the applications.